# Sharepoint Designer 2013 trouble joining lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, joined-view

I am attempting to join two lists, the idea is that I want to have two different sets of permissions for different parts of a list. I know column based security is not available so I figured by having two separate lists with a single view would allow different people to view/edit different data.

My problem is when trying to perform the joined data source via sharepoint designer 2013 most tutorials explain that after selecting two lists I can pick a shared column to use for the joining. This option however does not appear to me, the lists simply "join" and when the joined data source is displayed, it displays only one of the list's data while the columns from the other list are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting this link, I was able to complete the requirement by following this tutorial. One thing to note is that when you click into the data view web part you have to make sure you are inserting the Cursor in the right part of the XSL/HTML, then you choose your data from the Data Source Details pane and then INSERT SELECTED FIELD as a Joined Subview, then choose the related column

**http://www.macaalay.com/2013/12/17/join-two-sharepoint-lists-together-by-id/**

Comment: I thought merge will simply make the two lists into one as in, If I have a list with 3 items and a list with 2 items, the merged result is a list with 5 items. That is not what I'm looking for, as I need the info from one list to combine with the info from the other so that I have a list with 3 items, 1 of which has half the columns empty.

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to accomplish now. Let me get back to you on this

Comment: Tomasz, take a look at the link above, I edited my answer, the link above should give you what you need to accomplish, I was able to replicate what you are trying to do. One important thing to just note is that depending on where the cursor is in the XSL/HTML, it will give you different options from the INSERT SELECTED FIELD AS drop down... make sure you choose JOINED SUBVIEW

Comment: Was this able to answer your question?

Comment: We ended up going a different route, rather than joining two lists.